# index notation derivative mathematica/maple

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, maple

is there a way to take partial derivative with respect to the indices using Maple or Mathematica?

For instance,

```
$\dfrac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j}=\delta_{ij}$
```

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

mathematica's ability to work with abstract vectors is pretty limited. You can prove such a statement by example like this:

```
  x = {x1, x2, x3};
  And @@ (D[x[[#[[1]]]], x[[#[[2]]]]] ==
   KroneckerDelta @@ # & /@ Tuples[{1, 2, 3}, 2])
```

(* True *)